# Are styles on careers.so not working?

Tags: support, jobs, design

Are styles on [careers.so](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/faq) not working now?

[image]

Comment: Looks OK to me. When you open the developer tools, are there any blocked sites?

Comment: How to check for blocked sites in dev tool?

Comment: Any row that is in red in the network tab would be suspect. Check if you can access that domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it looks like some of the sites are blocked on the local network.

[image: Blocked sites]

btw this helped me get an intro to network tab. Thanks @Oded